# Number format conversion IEEE

Tags: java, modbus

I use SDM 220 meter to calculate energy from a electricity system using MODBUS RS485 protocol .but when I  read the register values, it gives in Hexadecimal format number (IEEE 32 bit standard format).. So how to convert register values correctly;

register value: 17261
actual value :237.9 Votls
 how do I convert register Values to get real value?

```
 master.connect();

                                int[] registerValues = master.readInputRegisters(1,0,14);


                              //  double voltage=registerValues[0]-17024;
                              //  double amperage=registerValues[6]/15000;
                                double units=(registerValues[12]);
```

Comment: Your question is missing a lot: description of the actual problem. Expected output for some inputs. And a code that you have written to solve your problem... How are we supposed to help? Please check the [mcve] as a good start.

Comment: You need to convert your register value to IEEE-754 float format, refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)

Comment: @Sanju thank you ! the link was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As (jlibModbus java lib I used as protocol)it uses 32bits by using 16bit 2 registers, I got two register values.

```
int[] registerValues = master.readInputRegisters(1,330,14);
int unitsReg1=registerValues[12];
int unitsReg2=registerValues[13];
float units=getRealRegisterValue(unitsReg1,unitsReg2);
```

then I wrote this method

```
private float getRealRegisterValue(int register1, int register2) {
     //Get binary string of register values
     String s1 = Integer.toBinaryString(register1);
        String s2 = Integer.toBinaryString(register2);

    //Append them respectively
    String b=s1+"s2";

    //get integer values 
    int intBits = Integer.parseInt(b, 2);
    System.out.println(intBits);
    //get float real value from IEEE 754 format
    float realValue = Float.intBitsToFloat(intBits);
    return realValue;   
}
```

I think this will be helpful to someone ,I have to spend a lot time on this.